How to draw the incomplete Dynkin diagrams as follow?
This a incomplete Dynkin diagram in the picture.
How to draw it in usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}?


Have a look at some of the tutorials here: https://tikz.dev/. I think this would best be done with nodes and edges.

Did you search this site for similar questions? For example, there is this one among others

This question is similar to: Dynkin-diagrams package labels problem. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please note that it is recommended to show what has been tried so far and also to state why other similar questions do not solve your specific problem. You seem to have changed your question now, so I do understand you issue better added an answer below.

You need to add the last node at the upper right by hand. The package manual has some examples that show how to add custom nodes if you scroll through it until the end:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\extraNode}[6]{
    \dynkinPlaceRootRelativeTo{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}
    \dynkinDefiniteSingleEdge{#1}{#2}
    \dynkinRootMark{o}{#1}
    \advance\dynkin@nodes by 1
    \dynkinLabelRoot{#1}{#6}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{dynkinDiagram}[%
    labels={1,2,2n+1},
    edge length=.5cm,
] A{oo.o}
    \extraNode{4}{3}{northeast}{right}{right}{2n+2}
\end{dynkinDiagram}
\end{document}


